# Boost converter 12V to 20V

Tags: power-supply, analog, boost

I am looking for a solution to step up voltage from 12 V to 20 V to supply a motor driver with a maximum current draw of 1 A. I have seen a couple of boost converters offered by TI which require a lot of additional components and more complex design, also some analog circuitry with MOSFETs and inductors and I am not sure if it will be robust and efficient. I want a more simple, efficient and low cost solution that doesn't complicate my current design. What are the possible suggestions to make this happen, what would be the most efficient solution?

Comment: How much current do you need?

Comment: Best suggestion is get one of those components and follow their recommended components for the external circuitry

Comment: Suggest replacing the motor with one that suits driven from 12 V.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find DC-DC converters using PWM controllers with external MOSFETs and inductors in just about every electronic product you have around you, so I would not rule them out if I were you.

If you don't want to deal with MOSFET and inductors, you have integrated modules which only requires external capacitors, for example Analog devices LTM4656: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm4656.html.

On to of that, you can buy a ready-made power supply to do everything for you.